# Select with double many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

Let consider the following situation (simplified for the question);

[image]

- A `Person` can have one, several or zero `Tool`
- A `Task` requires one, several or zero `Tool` to be performed

I would like to have the list of all the `Task` a given `Person` can perform, assuming that

- if the `Task` requires several `Tool`, the `Person` must have all of them (otherwise the `Task` is excluded from the list)
- if the `Task` requires no `Tool`, it is always selected
- if the `Person` has more `Tool` than required in the `Task`, it will obviously be selected as well

I tried to do that using various combination of `WHERE IN`, `WHERE NOT IN`, `WHERE EXISTS`, as well as some `JOIN` structure found in the [SQL join cheat sheet](http://dsin.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/sqljoins_cheatsheet.png). But without success: I always end up either with all `Task`, none, or only those which have at least one `Tool` also owned by the `Person`...

I use Doctrine's QueryBuilder, so if you have any idea, feel free to answer in pure SQL or QueryBuilder.

Comment: Awesome question - I'm fascinated by the idea.  Is there any way you can set up a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data to play with?  I want to try this, but am a little daunted by coming up with the schema and sample data.

Comment: Thanks for interest. Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52036/1